# Uploading files to Azure Blob Storage

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a conceptual question about uploading files to Azure blob storage. In a Django project of mine, I'm uploading files like so:

```
blob_service.put_block_blob_from_path(
                    'containername',
                    name,
                    path.join(path.join(PROJECT_ROOT,'uploads'),name),
                    x_ms_blob_content_type='image/jpg'
            )
```

Do these files *directly* get uploaded to the storage? Or do they first go to my VM, and are then transferred to the storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files are uploaded directly to the storage from wherever the code you mentioned is running.

If this code is running on your local computer, then the files are transferred directly from your local computer to storage.

If this code is running on a VM somewhere, the files are transferred from that VM to storage directly.

It is however your application's responsibility to make the user uploaded content make available on the remote machine where your code is running.